# Use OpenOffice from command line to convert HTML to RTF

Tags: bash, conversion, openoffice, cygwin

I'm trying to build a bash script in Cygwin that will convert HTML files to RTF. In OS X this is trivial with `textutils`, but that doesn't exist for regular Linux or Cygwin. Instead I'm trying to use OpenOffice from the command line.

I've read elsewhere that OpenOffice can run headlessly with a program normally installed as `/usr/bin/ooffice`, but in Cygwin under Windows this obviously doesn't work—the OpenOffice installer doesn't built native Cygwin symlinks and might not even install the Windows equivalent of `ooffice`.

How can I use OpenOffice from the command line in Cygwin to convert HTML files to RTF files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a really handy shell script called `unoconv` that handles conversion of any files from and to any file format that OpenOffice/LibreOffice supports. You can read up about it on [its site](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) and be sure to check out the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv). Many distros have packages for it that you can install easily, including, I believe, cygwin.

Once you have it installed, usage in your case would mean specifying an input html file and an output rtf file like this:

```
unoconv file.html file.rtf
```

All done :)

Of course this could be scripted to handle multiple file situations as well. If you are using `zsh`, you could run something like this to convert a whole folder of html files:

```
for file in *html; do
    unoconv "$file" "${file/html/rtf}"
done
```

Comment: @Andrew I hope you find it useful, but it's not exactly new. The [project's git repository](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) dates back to 2007, and that was an import from some over version control system that they migrated from.

Comment: Hmm. I missed that when looking. I assumed that it was new since it mentioned working with zero configuration on OS X on LO 3.6.x, which just came out recently. Regardless, it's awesome :)

Comment: unoconv is deprecated in favor of https://github.com/unoconv/unoserver/

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter).  It is a java wrapper around the OpenDoc Api for conversion.  Allows you to convert files like this:

```
java -jar jodconverter-cli-2.2.0.jar foo.html foo.rtf
```

It's also available in [python](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter).

instead of using the [openoffice SDK](http://download.openoffice.org/sdk/index.html) [DocumentSaver](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Office/DocumentHandling#DocumentSaver_and_DocumentConverter) class like this:

```
java -classpath .;./bin;\
                $OO/program/classes/jurt.jar;\
                $OO/program/classes/ridl.jar;\
                $OO/program/classes/sandbox.jar;\
                $OO/program/classes/unoil.jar;\
                $OO/program/classes/juh.jar  \
    DocumentSaver uno:socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager  file:///C:/test/foo.html file:///C:/test/foo.rtf
```

Comment: I went ahead with a variation of this. At first I went with Python and kept OpenOffice running as a background server, but then I found Pyth (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/) a purely Python-based converter. It's minimalistic, but it works great.

Comment: Are you still required to actually install OOo, or do the "wrapper" libraries include everything needed?  I see no explicit mention.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can help with the first part of your question. Here's an example of running OpenOffice from the Cygwin command line:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/OpenOffice.org\ 3/program/soffice.exe -help
```

That will give you a list of command line arguments. I didn't see any that would convert file types or even "Save As", but I didn't research the API. Perhaps you can fill in that part. I have OpenOffice.org 3.2 320m12(Build:9483).