# library for html to rtf conversion

Tags: linux, centos, php, centos-6

I am much needed the linux library for converting html document to rtf.

As currently, I have used CMS kind of functionality where html is stored in database. I need to convert it in rtf.

If any console library is available or any PHP class, then it would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unoconv`:

```
unoconv file.html file.rtf
```

Here is the  [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv) 
Here is the similar question: [use-openoffice-from-command-line-to-convert-html-to-rtf](https://superuser.com/questions/169931/use-openoffice-from-command-line-to-convert-html-to-rtf)

Comment: Thanks, I have to check the functionality as the user can also have MS Office. Thats why I want to see whether the rtf format would be well for Microsoft Office or not.

Comment: It is working fine, but there are 2 points to consider here. First one is, I am not able to manipulate the page setting(margin, padding) and page break perfectly. And another point is that it is a tough call to install unoconv on server. Lots of dependency issues came during installation on CentOS 6.